# MySQL: What are the fields required to make a paypal payment credits system in the database?

Tags: mysql, sql

Right now I have 3 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_payment_info` (
  `payment_info_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `payment_type` tinyint(2) NOT NULL, (for users to choose paypal or credit card)
  `num_credits` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `price_per_credits` float NOT NULL,
`payment_time_stamp` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`payment_info_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `tbl_paypal_info` (
  `paypal_info_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `paypal_email` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `payment_info_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`paypal_info_id`),
  KEY `tbl_paypal_info_ibfk_1` (`payment_info_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `tbl_paypal_info_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`payment_info_id`) REFERENCES `tbl_payment_info` (`payment_info_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `tbl_credit_card_info` (
  `credit_card_info_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `payment_info_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `card_fullname` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `credit_number` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `credit_card_type` tinyint(2) NOT NULL,
  `billing_address_Line_1` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `billing_address_line_2` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `billing_city` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `billing_country` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `billing_phone` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`credit_card_info_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

am I missing anything? is there any better ways to write it more efficiently? Any advice will be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't get it, I think that you store the data how you want in your own system.

Comment: hmmm... i've seen some tutorials about paypal ipn, maybe there're some fields that is required and it's missing here. Just want to double check to see if anything is missing.

Comment: You shouldn't store full credit card numbers in the database, especially as plaintext.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No idea if these might be all the fields missing, but the ones that stick out on the credit card table are:

- billing_state
- billing_zip
- credit_exp_date

On the PayPal table, you might also want to save the transactionId. I don't know if this is the intent of the **payment_info** column you have in that table, but if it is, you might want to change the field type from **int** to **varchar**, as paypal returns a mixture of letters and numbers in their transaction id's

And one comment, credit card numbers are at most 16 digits long.  You have a 20 char field for it.

My final comment on efficiency, is that I wouldn't waste space using UTF-8 on the first table. It doesn't really look as if it will be storing international characters.

Comment: so would you use default for the first table then?

Comment: Since it looks like mostly simple letters and numbers (unless the user_id field has any special values...) I'd go for ascii or latin1 at the most.

Mind you, this might be a bit of performance overkill that won't make a difference unless your tables grow huuuuuge